# PHP MySQLi Database Multiple Array Sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, sorting

I have a database with a structure such as code1 code2 code3 code4 code5. I'm trying to using a SQL query to check each column for a matching code and then return all results. So if the code is 000 and in one row that code appears in column label code3 and in another column label code4 I want to return all other information found on those rows. The idea is to create a system where these codes are logged in by users, I want to be able to search a particular code and then see any other codes that user or other users have entered as well. If a user enters the code 000 I want to search for code 000 and see any entries in my database and any other codes that were entered showing from order of most common to least.

So far no matter what array sorting I try I cannot search for a single code, return all matching rows, return all other codes found on those rows, and then sort them in DESC with a count displayed. I've tried various complicated MySQL queries and now I've been messing with arrays for hours. What am I missing?

Here's my code,

```
$query="SELECT * FROM codetables WHERE code1 = 555 OR code2 = 555 OR code3 = 555";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$array1 = array();
while(($x =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) { 
    $array1[] = $x; 
    $ax = array_count_values($ac);
    print_r($ax);
}
```

Now I've tried everything from using array_column to trying to merge arrays and even escaping an array and recreating it. There must be an easier way to return all information found on a row where a match is found and then organize that information in logical DESC order. I know that code looks basic and simple but it's what I had left after a lot of trial and error.

Comment: what is ` $ac`  here? did you try `array_multisort(array_column($array1, 0), SORT_DESC, $array1);` for sorting?

Comment: I left a variable incorrectly named when copying the code, my mistake. I just gave it a shot but I can't get it to produce any results.